# Separate World Mapping on Z axis and make them independent?

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes, world

My nodes config:

[image]

I'm trying to set the nodes in order to modify the top and bottom (+Z/-Z) independently with the Mapping Nodes, I also put a Map Range node to blend the +Z-Z coordinates

Changing the values of the Mapping nodes (Location Z or Scale Z) I don't get the desired effect.

The Mapping node (Bottom) should be able to Stretch on the Z axis (Only in the -Z part) with the Scale Z value so as to be homogeneous and blended with the upper part.

The Mapping (Top) node should do the same but at the top +Z

The biggest problem is that only 1 of the 2 mapping nodes will be right (Bottom) will control the Upper part of the world without affecting the upper one, while the other mapping (Top) will unfortunately change everything.

I wish I could just figure out how to configure the nodes to make independent with a feather boundary between -Z and +Z.

Oddly enough if I use the math greath Than (0.0) node instead of Map Range I get the desired result but without a gradient range, I'll get a sharp detachment.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, the space you're interested in is *Generated*. You can take its 0-1 Z coordinate, and use some mapping of that as a factor in a Color Mix between 2 manipulations of it:

[image]

Below, the mapped image is mixed,

[image]

but you could mix the vector-spaces directly:

[image]

Here, to scale the top half:

[image]

Comment: In your second example it doesn't change much from mine with map range, but it helped me to understand that the range must be much lower, in fact I set From Min = 0.01 From Max = 0.00 , You get similar result, the map range node and that Color Ramp in this case they can both replace each other. Personally I prefer the Map Range node as it has the inputs to better control the node also via group node. However, it works just fine as well as in your second example.

Comment: Hi, @Noob Cat.. You're right there.. I wound up with the _Color Ramp_ because I used color in it it earlier to visualize Z, and probably should have replaced it.(I have a standard ramp with thin constant stops near the ends to  see where 0,1, and ,5 are.)